# How to use a modal pop up to update data in a grid with a custom cell

Tags: tableview, javafx-8

I would like to be able to use a modal window to present the contents of a column to the user for editing.  I am not able to make this work, and I am not sure where I am going wrong.

I have provided a button in the table which will indicate if there are additional details (in this case comments).  When the user selects the button, I want to open a modal dialog to enter the data and when it closes, update the field.

[image]

I have gotten the majority of this wired up, but the data is not making it back to my model.  I have tried several things, and all without results.  It appears that the commit edit call I am making is not seeing the field as in "edit mode" and just skips.

This is my code for my custom table cell:

```
public class CommentTableCell<T> extends TableCell<T, String> {
private Button actionBtn;
private TextArea textArea;
public CommentTableCell(TableColumn<T, String> column) {
    super();

    actionBtn = new Button("my action");
    actionBtn.setTooltip(new Tooltip("Select to add/edit comments..."));
    actionBtn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            startEdit();
            System.out.println("Action: "+getItem());
            Stage commentStage = new Stage();
            AnchorPane ap = new AnchorPane();
            textArea = new TextArea();
            AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(textArea, 5.0);
            AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(textArea, 5.0);
            AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(textArea, 5.0);
            AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(textArea, 5.0);
            ap.getChildren().add(textArea);
            Scene commentScene = new Scene (ap, 200, 200);
            commentStage.setScene(commentScene);
            commentStage.show();
            commentStage.setOnCloseRequest(a -> {
                commitEdit(textArea.getText());
            });

// I have tried with an column.setOnEditCommit() as well as what is noted below which I found here, passing in the column.
                final TableView<T> tableView = getTableView();
                tableView.getSelectionModel().select(getTableRow().getIndex());
                tableView.edit(tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex(), column);
            }
        });
        setText(null);
    }

@Override
public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);
    actionBtn.getStyleClass().clear();
    setEditable(false);
    if (item != null && item.length() > 0) {
        actionBtn.getStyleClass().add(CSSConstants.GRID_BUTTON_EDIT_COMMNET);
        setGraphic(actionBtn);
    } else if (!empty)  {
        actionBtn.getStyleClass().add(CSSConstants.GRID_BUTTON_ADD_COMMNET);
        setGraphic(actionBtn);
    } else {
        setGraphic(null);
    }
}
```

}

During the execution it hits the commitEdit() call and the following has isEditing in the TableCell as null:

```
@Override public void commitEdit(T newValue) {
    if (! isEditing()) return;
```

My table looks basically like this:

```
TableView<SomeDTO> addressTableView = new TableView()
addressTableView.setItems(sortedItems);
addressTableView.setEditable(true);


commentsColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellValue -> cellValue.getValue().commentsProperty());
        commentsColumn.setCellFactory(tc -> new CommentTableCell<SomeDTO>(commentsColumn));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to my issue - though I am not sure it is the best way or not.

I have changed my CommentTableCell as follows and it seems to work like a charm..

```
public class CommentTableCell<T> extends TableCell<T, String> {
private Button actionBtn;
public CommentTableCell() {
    super();

    actionBtn = new Button("my action");
    actionBtn.setTooltip(new Tooltip("Select to add/edit comments..."));
    actionBtn.setOnAction(event ->
        {

            Stage commentStage = new Stage();
            AnchorPane ap = new AnchorPane();
            TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
            AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(textArea, 5.0);
            AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(textArea, 5.0);
            AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(textArea, 5.0);
            AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(textArea, 5.0);
            ap.getChildren().add(textArea);
            Scene commentScene = new Scene (ap, 200, 200);
            commentStage.setScene(commentScene);

            if(getItem() != null) {
                String myValue = getItem();
                textArea.setText(myValue);
                textArea.selectAll();
            }

            commentStage.show();
            commentStage.setOnCloseRequest(a -> {
                commitEdit(textArea.getText());
            });

    });
}

@Override
@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "rawtypes"})
public void commitEdit(String item) {

    if (isEditing()) {
        super.commitEdit(item);
    } else {
        final TableView table = getTableView();
        if (table != null) {
            TablePosition position = new TablePosition(getTableView(),
                    getTableRow().getIndex(), getTableColumn());
            CellEditEvent editEvent = new CellEditEvent(table, position,
                    TableColumn.editCommitEvent(), item);
            Event.fireEvent(getTableColumn(), editEvent);
        }
        updateItem(item, false);
        if (table != null) {
            table.edit(-1, null);
        }

    }
}

@Override
public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);
    actionBtn.getStyleClass().clear();
    setEditable(false);
    if (item != null && item.length() > 0) {
        actionBtn.getStyleClass().add(CSSConstants.GRID_BUTTON_EDIT_COMMNET);
        setGraphic(actionBtn);
    } else if (!empty)  {
        actionBtn.getStyleClass().add(CSSConstants.GRID_BUTTON_ADD_COMMNET);
        setGraphic(actionBtn);
    } else {
        setGraphic(null);
    }
}
```

}